# Shouldn't every .swift file be a class?

Tags: objective-c, swift, class, model-view-controller

I have *some* experience in ObjC and I just started learning Swift. In Objc everything is a class through `@interface` in `.h` and `@implementation` of `.m`, or in other Swift classes that I have seen everything is usually in some form of

`class MyCustomClassInhertingfrom: SomeFoundationClass { //methods & properties}`

Yet here in some class named `pancakeHouse.Swift` there is no mention of the keyword `class` **WHY?** Isn't this a Model Class? Doesn't this break the MVC design pattern? Is this happening because of new powerful features of enums& structs vs class in Swift?_____I am confused obviously!

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

enum PriceGuide : Int {
  case Unknown = 0
  case Low = 1
  case Medium = 2
  case High = 3
}

extension PriceGuide : CustomStringConvertible {
  var description : String {
    switch self {
    case .Unknown:
      return "?"
    case .Low:
      return "$"
    case .Medium:
      return "$$"
    case .High:
      return "$$$"
    }
  }
}

enum PancakeRating {
  case Unknown
  case Rating(Int)
}

extension PancakeRating {
  init?(value: Int) {
    if value > 0 && value <= 5 {
      self = .Rating(value)
    } else {
      self = .Unknown
    }
  }
}

extension PancakeRating {
  var ratingImage : UIImage? {
    guard let baseName = ratingImageName else {
      return nil
    }
    return UIImage(named: baseName)
  }

  var smallRatingImage : UIImage? {
    guard let baseName = ratingImageName else {
      return nil
    }
    return UIImage(named: "\(baseName)_small")
  }

  private var ratingImageName : String? {
    switch self {
    case .Unknown:
      return nil
    case .Rating(let value):
      return "pancake_rate_\(value)"
    }
  }
}



 struct PancakeHouse {
  let name: String
  let photo: UIImage?
  let thumbnail: UIImage?
  let priceGuide: PriceGuide
  let location: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
  let details: String
  let rating: PancakeRating
}

extension PancakeHouse {
   init?(dict: [String : AnyObject]) {
    guard let name = dict["name"] as? String,
      let priceGuideRaw = dict["priceGuide"] as? Int,
      let priceGuide = PriceGuide(rawValue: priceGuideRaw),
      let details = dict["details"] as? String,
      let ratingRaw = dict["rating"] as? Int,
      let rating = PancakeRating(value: ratingRaw) else {
        return nil
    }

    self.name = name
    self.priceGuide = priceGuide
    self.details = details
    self.rating = rating

    if let imageName = dict["imageName"] as? String where !imageName.isEmpty {
      photo = UIImage(named: imageName)
    } else {
      photo = nil
    }

    if let thumbnailName = dict["thumbnailName"] as? String where !thumbnailName.isEmpty {
      thumbnail = UIImage(named: thumbnailName)
    } else {
      thumbnail = nil
    }

    if let latitude = dict["latitude"] as? Double,
      let longitude = dict["longitude"] as? Double {
        location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
    } else {
      location = nil
    }
  }
}

extension PancakeHouse {
  static func loadDefaultPancakeHouses() -> [PancakeHouse]? {
    return self.loadPancakeHousesFromPlistNamed("pancake_houses")
  } 

  static func loadPancakeHousesFromPlistNamed(plistName: String) -> [PancakeHouse]? {
    guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(plistName, ofType: "plist"),
      let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String : AnyObject]] else {
        return nil
    }

    return array.map { PancakeHouse(dict: $0) }
                .filter { $0 != nil }
                .map { $0! }
  }
}

extension PancakeHouse : CustomStringConvertible {
  var description : String {
    return "\(name) :: \(details)"
  }
}

extension PancakeHouse: Equatable {
}

func ==(lhs: PancakeHouse, rhs: PancakeHouse) -> Bool {
  return lhs.name == rhs.name
}
```

**Note:** I would appreciate an answer that also includes comparison of the `.swift` vs `.h` + `.m` ie don't just consider this as a specific question, consider it as a general question and explain or link the prerequisites's details needed to understand this question)

Comment: MVC and OOP have nothing a common. You can use OOP (objects, classes) to implement MVC pattern but you don't have to.
Also, classes and structs are *almost* the same from architecture perspective. You can use either of them to implement an object.

Comment: The reason for header (`*.h`) files to exist is purely historical. They are used because compilers 40 years ago needed them and we cannot remove them from the language now. `.swift` file is `.m` file and you just don't need `.h`.

Comment: There is this [WWDC2015 video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/), that touches some of this topics, maybe it helps to understand further into this subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`pancakeHouse.swift` defines `PancakeHouse` and all the various things that go with it. That is perfectly good Swift style. There is no `class` here because `PancakeHouse` happens to be a `struct`, which is also perfectly good Swift style (and mildly preferred). Structs are much like classes in Swift, in that they can have data and methods (and extensions).

ObjC does not require that each class be defined in its own .h/.m pair, but it is fairly typical ObjC style to do so. That said, even in ObjC there are exceptions. It is common to have mutable subclasses defined in the same file as their base class (`NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` are both defined in `NSArray.h`). Swift style has evolved towards lumping related things together more closely. One style makes it easier to find something if you know its name. The other makes it easier to find related concepts together. Both have their advantages, and once people are used to one they tend to believe that that one is obviously correct. But they're just different ways of organizing.

Note that this file also makes use of Swift extensions to break up related methods. That is also common and good Swift. Old ObjC did that with categories, but it's much less common to organize ObjC code that way today (categories are used for other things now). Again, neither is deeply correct. It's just the styles that have evolved.

Comment: I see.... **Must** the naming of the swift file match the `struct PancakeHouse` ? I mean it's also defining 2 other enums in it as well. Couldn't it match any of their names? To me the swift file just seems like a wrapper with no semantic meaning attached to it. right?

Comment: right. It could have just been named pancake.swift. I have a file called `Logging.swift` that defines a `Log` struct and other things related to logging. Nothing in the system is actually called "Logging." That said, it is typical in Cocoa programming to put your View Controllers especially into files that share their name. And in most cases you should lean towards naming files after their major type. But minor types tend to get clumped together with their major type. That's just how Swift has evolved so far (minor types are more common in Swift than ObjC).

Comment: Good summary. To tangentially follow up on the "structs mildly preferred" thing: watch out. Value types are great, but because they're one of the new shiny things about Swift they tend to get overused. In this case, you might start having trouble if you started making, say, ratings user-editable. (Partly that also depends on how you build the rest of the app.) Also... mmmm, pancakes.

Comment: I just ran into a small issue: I had 2 function with same names in different swift files. e.g. I had func abc() written in file x and file y. This confused my debugging mindset. I thought I was debugging func abc from file y, but I was on file x. For this reason I think it may be better to place a distinct class in a file that has the class name. (Though still as you said, keep mutable classes in the same file)

Answer (score 1):

Swift files just need valid swift code.  That's all.  In this case, your swift file is just defining two enums.  Generally it's better practice to put each enum (and its extension) in it's own .swift file, but that's really just personal opinion when you get right down to it.

A .m is the implementation of the .h interface.  It's a pain in the !@#$ to keep those two things always up to date.  Swift makes this much easier by just merging them into one thing/file, and your entire project automatically sees it based on the access you've set.  If you don't set any access, like the example above, then you have 'internal' which means the whole project.

Comment: You **forgot** the struct definition...Oh...I see. So in theory this is more like composed bundled .swift file, which has definition for `enum PriceGuide` and `PancakeRating` and for `struct PancakeHouse`. In ObjC if we ever wanted to do this, we had to put them in a `.h` & `.m` file which would eventually make it enveloped in a class right?

Comment: If you find it a pain to keep the .h and .m files in sync then you may be putting too much in the .h file. There's very few things mentioned in both files if you do it right.

Comment: Anything that's public is mentioned in both.  If you change the signature of a public method, you have to edit that same thing in two places.  That's why .h files were always a pain.

Answer (score 1):

There are two philosophies the compiler writers could take on this question:

- **Each public class needs a file with the matching name** - this is Java's way of doing it. Although it is minimally restrictive, the logic behind it is to let the compiler find class references without looking through all the files. It also helps programmers organize their code.
- **Do it your own way** - this is the road taken by Swift, along with C, C#, Objective-C. Essentially, compiler writers tell you that their compiler will find your classes no matter where you put them, letting you organize your code in a way that you find the most intuitive for you and your team.

Comment: Ohhk. I am starting to question my whole understanding on Structs and enums...AFAIK in contrary to Swift which everything is by itself—not needing a class...in ObjC everything's visibility or access is managed by a class, which means that if you want to use a struct you **must** import its class `.h` file. right?

Comment: @asma22 Obj-C classes also have public data members that you *can* use if you want (it's *not* usually a good idea, but that's a different story). Structs, on the other hand, are C animals, with access control replaced by including or not including the header file.

Comment: I just ran into a small issue: I had 2 function with same names in different swift files. e.g. I had func abc() written in file x and file y. This confused my debugging mindset. I thought I was debugging func abc from file y, but I was on file x. For this reason I think it may be better to place a distinct class in a file that has the same name. (Though still as Rob said, keep mutable classes in the same file or separate anything that can independently have a syntactic meaning)